# Find the row index of a selected row element in jsoup

Tags: row, jsoup

```
static public void main( String[] args ) {
   Document playerpage =
      Jsoup.connect("http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diego_Forl%C3%A1n").get();
   Elements table = playerpage.getElementsByTag("table").select("table.infobox");
   Elements ind = table.select("tr:contains(Club information)");
```

As you can see, I successfully selected the row of the table which contains the text: `Club information`.

How can I return the row index of this element as I want to use the number for the next search?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    Document playerpage = Jsoup.connect("http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diego_Forl%C3%A1n").get();
    Elements table = playerpage.select("table.infobox > tbody > tr");
    int rowCount = 0;
    for (Element e : table) {
        if (e.text().contains("Club information")) {
            System.out.println("Row: " + rowCount);
            System.out.println(e);
        }
        rowCount++;
    }
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I"ll try to make it work as I want, but your answer helped.